# Installation 16.04

Tags: system-installation

When I download https://mirrors.nl.eu.kernel.org/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso and create a bootable USB-thumbdrive, installation fails. As a matter of fact, it doesn't even start but I get an error
"Missing parameter in configuration file
Unknown keyword in configuration file"
I have no clue what to do next. Who can put me on a track to get it installed?

Comment: How did you create the USB?  Are you sure the target machine is not UEFI (likely 64 bit better for that)?

Comment: From Ubuntu 09-10: System->Administration-> USB Startup Disk Creator Both with the i386 flavor and the AMD 64 flavor

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, Starup Disk Creator on older releases usually does not work on newer ISOs.  Even the 14.04 version cannot create a 16,04 USB.  The easy workaround is to use dd, although mkusb offers some additional safely checks to avoid common errors like overwriting the system partition. See the link [mkusb help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

---

Further down the page, you can download mkusb directly (maybe an older version) at [mkusb download](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/)  Dont forget, dd works just fine, as long as you know which disk you are writing to!  Even the 16.04 Startup Disk Creator uses dd -- too bad, since it no longer gives you the option of having persistence.

Comment: I did what it says under "Quick start manual and mkusb PPA" but after a whole slew of "failed to fetch" 404 IP not found messages, I get "Couldn't find package mkusb". I would think that the 404 are due to the fact that I'm using an outdated Ubuntu. What might I try next?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very old version of Ubuntu (or some other old linux distro), you can use **mkusb-bas**, which runs in text mode, but *the basic feature is the same as in standard mkusb: it 'wraps a safety belt around dd'* to help you select the correct target drive (and avoid overwriting valuable files in other drives).

See the following link where you find a basic mode quick start manual and the program itself (a bash shellscript),

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#mkusb version 7.4.x - mkusb-bas](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#mkusb_version_7.4.x_-_mkusb-bas)